# How do I get the scalaz IDEA live templates working for the symbolic methods?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, scalaz

Many of the methods in [scalaz](http://github.com/scalaz/scalaz) have symbolic unicode equivalents, such as `forever` and `∞` (of course, I have this the wrong way round, the symbolic methods really have ASCII equivalents).

The project contains a [live templates XML file](http://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/master/etc/intellij/livetemplate/scalaz.xml) for IDEA so these can be *auto-completed*, I believe by using the `forever+TAB` shortcut (in the above instance).

I can't figure out how to import this live template into IDEA and actually use it, though. How can I do that?

Comment: I also use start IntelliJ with -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, and set the IDE and project File Encoding to UTF-8. This avoids a few other problems with Unicode identifiers, for example, incorrect parsing of the textual output of the compiler.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Live Templates XML file should be placed under IDEA configuration directory, **templates** subdirectory.

IDEA configuration folder location would depend on your platform:

- **Windows:** USERPROFILE\.IntelliJIdeaXX\config
- **Linux:** ~/.IntelliJIdeaXX/config
- **Mac OS X:** ~/Library/Preferences/IntelliJIdeaXX

Where XX is IDEA version (90 for IDEA 9.x).

Make sure to close IDEA before copying the XML into the templates directory.

Comment: Worth saying as well that one needs to check the encoding of the source files is UTF-8 to get this to work.