# How can I configure IDEA to automatically replace => with ⇒ and -> with →?

Tags: scala, unicode, intellij-idea

How can I configure IDEA to *automatically* replace `=>` with `⇒` and `->` with `→`?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your rollback. I was working from a huge list that I kept refreshing until it was gone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681429/how-do-i-get-the-scalaz-idea-live-templates-working-for-the-symbolic-methods) which makes use of IntelliJ's "Live Templates", in this case scalaz mappings in XML form saved as a file rather than entered from the GUI. This, I guess, is fine with scalaz as all the unicode aliased functions and methods are already present.

Answer (score 6):

Scalariform will do this for you (if appropriately configured).  I would imagine that what you want is something that can auto-expand those sequences into the relevant unicode characters though *as you type*.  I honestly don't know whether or not this is possible in IDEA.

Comment: +1, Scalariform + IDEA Live Templates is what I needed.

Answer (score 6):

With IntelliJ 2016.1.4, which I am using, things has become easier.

`File -> (Other Settings-> Default Settings) |Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> Scala`

Select tab `Other`

1. select option `Replace => with unicode symbol`
2. select option `Replace -> with unicode symbol`

> However if one wants to support other unicode characters as in scalaz, then
> maybe, Live Template might still be the way to go. I haven't verified it.
>
> With IntelliJ 2019.x.x, I recommend using Font Ligature along with Jetbrains Font like Jetbrains Mono especially when the use of unicode arrows are getting deprecated in Scala 2.13+. Besides, I found that the unicode symbol don't gel with Scala Repl.

Answer (score 3):

Please follow the steps in the image:

[image: steps.]