# some ligatures do not work correctly in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

Version: 2019-12 (4.14.0)
Build id: 20191212-1212

It seems all arrow ligatures are dead in eclipse...
I have tried `Cascadia Code` `Consolas Ligaturized` and `Fira Code` and gotten some result.So the problem is not about these font but about eclipse render.
They all work well in idea.
example:(copy -> create a text file -> paste)

```
<!-- --> <-- ->> <<- -> <- => <=> <==> ==> <== >>= =<< -- := =:= == !== != <= >= // /** /* */ && .& || !! :: >> << ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ __
```

in eclipse:
[image]

and in idea:
[image]

I don't find any configuration about ligatures.
But I find some font render bugs about eclipse...So maybe there is no solution now I think...

Maybe related bug link:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=398656

Before I got this bug: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=536562#c92  but ligatures works fine.After using new version that fix this, some ligatures begin not to work.

I try to reproduce it in older version.see:
[image]

Comment: Please give a step-by-step instruction how to reproduce this issue. Are you talking about the editor (which one) or the _Console_ view? What steps did you try exactly? Please add links to the bugs you found.

Comment: @howlger I add some extra infoes. :)

Comment: Where are the ligatures in your example? Or do you expect that some characters are automatically replaced by Unicode characters, e.g. `-->` should become automatically `→`?

Comment: `<!-- --> <-- ->> <<- -> <- => <=> <==> ==> <== >>= =<<  <= >=` these one.I put Idea's result for comparison.Yes, just like this. @howlger

Comment: `<!-- --> <-- ->> <<- -> <- => <=> <==> ==> <== >>= =<< <= >=` ← These are just 60 ASCII characters. There is no ligature here. Maybe you are talking about [_"Replace ... with unicode symbol"_](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47864226/6505250) or something else.

Comment: This so weird.I use java not scala and they actually worked in older version(2019-03) when this bug https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=536562#c92 happened.I try to reproduce it in older version. @howlger

Comment: I don't mean all these 60 characters but the space split ones like `->` `>=`... ... @howlger I just wonder display them correctly is a bug of older verison ?